# Language in mdi forms

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with set lenguage to MDI forms.
In my main form I have a menustrip and I use resource file for translate

I wanted to know if I'm doing the right thing

My code is this (Example):

```
Public Class Main

   Public SNFrm As New SalesNote

   Private Sub SetLanguage()

      SNFrm.Text = My.Resources....
      SNFrm.AcceptBtn.Text = My.Resources...

   End Sub

   Private Sub MenuSalesNote_Click(......)

    SNFrm = New SalesNote
    SNFrm.MdiParent = Me
    SNFrm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    SNFrm.Show()

   End Sub

End Class
```

Then, in My SalesNote Form_Closing Event

```
Main.SNFrm.Dispose()
```

is this correctly? Help!

Comment: You don't need the `Main.SNFrm.Dispose()` in `Form_Closing`. event.

Comment: What exactly is your problem by the way?

Comment: @Edper is it correct? I instance the SalesNote before load form and then again in MenuSalesNote_Click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your `IsMdiContainer` is set to `True` in your property, if not you could set it programatically like when your Form loads:

```
Private Sub Main_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.IsMdiContainer = True
End Sub
```

You don't need to create an instance right away for your SalesNote form:

```
  Public SNFrm As SalesNote
```

Because you are instantiating it here:

```
 Private Sub MenuSalesNote_Click(......)
  SNFrm = New SalesNote
  SNFrm.MdiParent = Me
  SNFrm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
  SNFrm.Show()
 End Sub
```

However if your `SetLanguage()` procedure is called before `MenuSalesNote_Click()` then it's good to instantiate it right away or you could instantiate it instead here:

```
Private Sub SetLanguage()
  SNFrm = New SalesNote    
  SNFrm.Text = My.Resources....
  SNFrm.AcceptBtn.Text = My.Resources...
End Sub
```

However you don't instantiate it in `MenuSalesNote_Click()` anymore:

```
 Private Sub MenuSalesNote_Click(......)
  SNFrm.MdiParent = Me
  SNFrm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
  SNFrm.Show()
 End Sub
```

You could also achieve this by checking if there is already instance of SalesNote form like:

```
 Private Sub MenuSalesNote_Click(......)

   If (SNFrm is Nothing) Then
      SNFrm = New SalesNote
   End if
   SNFrm.MdiParent = Me
   SNFrm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
   SNFrm.Show()

 End Sub


 Private Sub SetLanguage()

   If (SNFrm is Nothing) Then
      SNFrm = New SalesNote
   End if
   SNFrm.Text = My.Resources....
   SNFrm.AcceptBtn.Text = My.Resources...

 End Sub
```

Comment: If he is only wanting a single instance of his SNFrm, having it declared at the module level and verifying that it is nothing before instantiating his form will achieve that.

Comment: @Edper but if I don't create an instance of SalesNote when I try to translate it throw exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  the sub SetLanguage() is in load form

Comment: @Edper, I need the translate in SetLanguage because the user can change the language from main ffrom.

Comment: @Edper the last code, I need to instance the SalesNote at Public SNFrm As New SalesNote ?

Comment: Thanks for all @Edper Genius!

Comment: I'm far from being Genius my friend..lol. But glad to be of help. Happy coding and GOD bless.